# AAD B2C - Changing Page Title of a User Flow without using a Custom UI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have been trying to find ways in the AAD B2C portal to change my user flow page title but couldnt find any.  My SignIn user flow shows "Choose your account" on the page title which does not make sense.  Is there a way to update this without using a Custom UI?

Answer (score 0):

I think custom HTML may be the only way to change the title.
It is set by the HTML loaded by the page.
For example a test sign up/sign in user flow I have loads `https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/static/tenant/default/unified.cshtml?ui_locales=en&slice=001-000&dc=AM2`,
which contains this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign up or sign in</title>
    <!-- Rest omitted -->
</head>
</html>
```

I was thinking it could be possible through language customization, but I could not find a string ID for the title e.g. at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids.

Comment: Thanks I looked into language customizations also and didn't see anything.  You would think something as trivial as this would be easy to customize, I have a feeling that I would need to indeed use a Custom Html.